# How to increment a number in a String in Java?

Tags: java

I want to increment a number in a string in Java 8.
Like this:

```
String lifes = "3";
lifes--
```

But i know that way is impossible, does you know other way to do it?

Comment: Don't. If you want to do arithmetic on numbers, use a numeric type to store the number.

Comment: @AndyTurner But i have a scenario where i don't able to store it in integer or float.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Integer.parseInt("3") + 1
```

The above statement results 4 which means we are parsing the String value as Integer and then incrementing in here, hope it helps!

Answer (score 2):

If the string only contains the number, I'd do something like this -

```
lifes = String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(lifes) - 1);
```